# Quick question about solution to Chapter 14 Question 5(i) in Spivak's Calculus: Find a function $g$ such that $\int_0^x t g(t)dt=x+x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

Question 5(i) in Chapter 14 of Spivak's *Calculus* reads as follows:

> Find a function $g$ such that$\displaystyle \int_0^x t g(t)dt=x+x^2$

The solution manual proposes the following function  as a viable possibility:

> $g(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{t}+2 \quad &\text{ if t $\gt 0$} \\0 \quad &\text{ if $t=0$} \end{cases}$

I just wanted to make sure that the specification of the value that $g$ takes on when $t=0$ is completely arbitrary. Any value $M \in\mathbb R$ would have worked, right?

In fact, the integral is completely agnostic to the value that $g$ takes on at $0$ because, by definition, $\int_0^0=0$ and at $x=0$, we obviously have that $x+x^2=0+0^2=0$. This will always be the case regardless of the finite value that $g(0)$ is assigned. Is this correct?

Comment: I fully agree (and I appreciate the term "agnostic").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you could have taken any value for $g(0)$, you would not change the value of the integral, and the function $g$ would not be continuous in any case. In fact, you could change the values of the integrand at countably many points and still get the same result for the Riemann integral. In full generality, the set of discontinuities has to have Lebesgue measure zero. This is known as the *Lebesgue-Vitali theorem*.